# Application Loader (Apple) stuck on "Sending API usage to iTunes Connect"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, application-loader

I am submitting an iOS app to the App Store using Application Loader, however, it never gets past the "**Sending API usage to iTunes Connect**" stage. There is no error - this stage just doesn't complete.

I have verified that the Mac is connecting to the internet (I can visit websites). Also, the app is tiny (6MB) so this can't conceivably just be a long upload. I've tried leaving this for 20 minutes.

The background to this is that I developed in Flash CS5 on a Windows PC, built it for distribution there, and now on the Mac I am loading the final file into Application Loader to submit it. It verifies/validates the file just fine, but won't go beyond this point.

Any ideas anyone? Perhaps it's a network issue?

Comment: On further inspection, it looks like this problem was essentially the same as getting an "SSL connection could not be established" error. The problem was the network - Application Loader couldn't connect. I tried it on a different network and there was no problem.

Comment: I had this problem when accessing the Internet using a WiFi router - I imagine port forwarding was amiss in some fashion.

Comment: sometimes it takes LOTS of tries. just wait a few minutes and try again. i succeeded at the 20th try or something..

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem when behind a firewall.
I got around it by going to Xcode > Contents > Applications > Application Loader > Contents > MacOS > itms > java > lib  - Open net.properties with TextEdit and change the line 
`# https.proxyPort=443`
 to `https.proxyPort=80`.  This enables the application to use the HTTP port for HTTPS. Worked straight away after this. Hope this helps.

Comment: But that line is disabled, right? The '#' is a comment marker. Changing it shouldn't have any effect. So are you sure that actually is what solved it?

Comment: user2957268 had it correctly as a workaround. Except that you need to remove the # as radnoise indicated. old line: # https.proxyPort=443 new line:
https.proxyPort=80

Comment: This is a working solution if you remove the # too indeed, so I edited it to let it be right.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a different approach using your iPhone. Disconnect ethernet internet cable connection (if you have one) and/or switch off wifi connection on your mac. Switch off your iPhone's wifi connection so G3 or G4 is active and turn on personal hotspot. Connect your iPhone with a usb cable with your computer and check in System Preferences -> Network if you're connected to internet via usb with iPhone. Start delivering your app with Application Loader program on your computer via your iPhone's internet connection. And yes you will cross the “Sending API usage to iTunes Connect” barrier and you will be able to upload the package to the iPhone store. At least I was!

Answer (score 3):

If your Mac is has both a WiFi and an Ethernet connection, try turning off WiFi. That solved the problem for me (this time anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I solved only **rebooting** mac.

I'm still searching for a less drastic solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had my DNS set up to Google DNS. I removed the DNS settings and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off iphone's wifi worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode Organiser > Upload to App Store or  Application Loader?

I found I had the same issue when going though Xcode Organiser so tried it from the Application Loader (found within Xcodes application files) and it worked just fine. If that doesn't work there is a detailed activity log you can check to get a more detailed error.

Other things to try 
- check your firewall settings, maybe temporary disable them. 
- use an alternative connection, another wifi hotspot if you are on a MacBook, if not do what Oliver said and use your iPhone's cellular data.

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to a VPN, disconnected and problem was solved.