# Stuck on "Sending API usage to iTunes Connect"

Tags: air, app-store, app-store-connect, starling-framework, application-loader

I try to upload my game developed with Starling to the appstore but the "Application loader" stuck on "Sending API usage to iTunes Connect", 10 days ago the upload was successful, the new version have only a different line of code then the way to compile is same.

Somebody have this problem?

Somebody have a solution?

I try with this but no work for me:

[Can't Submit App to App Store: "Sending API Usage to iTunes Connect" either times out or loses connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712144/cant-submit-app-to-app-store-sending-api-usage-to-itunes-connect-either-time)

[Application Loader (Apple) stuck on "Sending API usage to iTunes Connect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395000/application-loader-apple-stuck-on-sending-api-usage-to-itunes-connect)

Comment: I had this issue a few months ago. My computer was unable to finish submission (I couldn't even load iTunes Connect) but my boss's computer was able to. So try either restarting your machine or try another machine, if possible. Make sure you close any network monitoring software, as well (i.e. Fiddler2, Charles, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I changed 1 line of code, and it gets stuck here too.

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue for most of the developer. You may go with Application loader to upload build or you need to restart your wifi or mac. and then it will work. I faced this issue many times there is no specific reason for this.

Comment: Of course there's a reason - it's just that nobody knows what it is yet. Uploading a file shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Chalk it up to apple's crappy DX (developer experience).

Comment: I've done everything, from restarting my router to restarting my whole computer.. nothing worked. I'm trying to upload my app for almost 3 hours and everytime I get a timeout. Apple really is the new black sheep on the market (pointing at Safari, IOS core webkit and xcode.. its a mess).

Comment: @LaneRettig DX is the right word for it. I cant even believe that apple didn't even care about going to the EdgeConf, even microsoft got that "browsers are important" by now. Apple doesn't give a damn shit about fluid development processes and in two years they will get an impact from that behaviour - its just like raising a child, if you don't take responsibilities you gonna end up with a little messed up piece of... nag. Microsoft learned that the hard way, now apple is the next in the row. For all of you: learn from history it will save you from making bad decisions!