# Cannot submit Xcode Archive to Itunes Connect. "Uploading Archive: Sending API Usage to Itunes Connect"

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

Hello Ive sent a version of my app one week ago through Xcode 6 and it didn't have any problem. Today Ive tried to upload a new version of my App via Xcode and when uploading, the progress bar stays in "Sending API usage to Itunes Connect". It doesn't give me any errors, nor warnings, it just stays like that forever.

Ive been looking in google and also in here, and found a lot of solutions (ones more logical than others). Well, Ive tried ALL those solutions, I've created new provision profiles, restarted my computer, restart Xcode, changed "netinfo", connect to new wifi, among others.

Its really driving me crazy since I didn't do anything, it just stopped working.

There are a lot of question with this same topic on the internet (including StackOverflow) and I think there is no one ultimate answer that really explain why this happen. Ive seen very detailed answers but none of them worked for me.

Some of this questions are:

[1) Can't Submit App to App Store: “Sending API Usage to iTunes Connect” either times out or loses connection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712144/cant-submit-app-to-app-store-sending-api-usage-to-itunes-connect-either-time)

[2) Application Loader (Apple) stuck on “Sending API usage to iTunes Connect”.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395000/application-loader-apple-stuck-on-sending-api-usage-to-itunes-connect)

[3) Stuck on “Sending API usage to iTunes Connect”.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413034/stuck-on-sending-api-usage-to-itunes-connect)

If I export the archive into an .ipa I can upload it with application loader. I don't know why I can't do it with Xcode. Ive always used Xcode for this.

The reason I want to know how to do it with Xcode is that I don't know if uploading only the .ipa and configuring in app purchases only directly via itunes connect's webpage without doing it in application loader(the button that says "New In-app Purchases" template) , will also work.

I hope someone could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I "solved" the same issue by disconnecting my wifi and using my phone as a hotspot. Such an irritating problem than Apple doesn't seem to care to fix

Comment: I'm expiring this in a even crazier way: After the "Sending API usage to iTunes Connect" state I can't connect to the internet. My whole Mac seems to be locked away from the internet until I restart my router.

Comment: happens to me as well. Sent in the first archive without any issue, and hit the same issue for the second upload.

Comment: happens to me also, started since 6.3.1. didn't manage to solve it yet

Comment: Is anyone using a Fortigate firewall with this problem? We've noticed that while experiencing this problem, our firewall displays an "impossible" upload speed of 85Mbps during the upload. No other type of upload causes this problem - ONLY uploads to iTunes connect.  @eskimo ?

Answer (score 33):

1. minimise the organiser window
2. reopen it from mac floating menubar

This seems to be refreshing the connection while online. Works for me.

Comment: Weird, but this helped. Thanks!

Comment: This will only refresh the view and cancel the upload! Try it directly after hitting upload and you'll see that it'll display that the upload was successful. But in fact, nothing was uploaded :/

Comment: Hi, it's a hack. But clearly, this hack already helped few other SO users.

Comment: Weird and amazing!

Comment: Holy smokes, what?? That worked after being stuck on "Verifying..." for 10 minutes.

Comment: What the hell, sat here for 10 minutes and this immediately worked.

Comment: Worked for me, as well. Thank you!

Comment: Worked. What an absolute joke Apple is

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem a few minutes ago, let me explain what I did:

1. Restart your router/modem
2. Restart your Mac
3. Set the active scheme in Xcode for iOS Device
4. Make a new archive
5. Validate before submit

These steps work perfectly for me, hope that helps.

Comment: Restarting the mac did it for me (I tried the other steps without restarting, didn't work)

Comment: @you786 Yep,  everything is changed now this is an old answer. El Capitan works great for now.

Comment: Validating did it for me :).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem. I can't upload from my office, but can upload from my home. I assumed that my office's internet connection has problem with Apple server. If you get problem with Xcode to upload, you can download Application Loader separately from iTunes connect and try with that and wait for passing sending api usage state.

Comment: Using application loader works just fine for me. But the question is really about why Xcode Stopped working in my particular case.

Comment: Which firewall does your office use?

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair We use Fortigate - and I wonder if it's just a problem with that appliance. It would be good if you could find out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

Seems to be working for a lot of others - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make this work on XCode 7.1.

I had to upgrade to 7.1.1, which allowed me to export the binary for App Store Deployment, and then use the Application Loader to upload the app for review.

Absolutely crazy, Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that instead of restarting your router and machine etc, simply clicking 'Renew DHCP Lease' in the TCP/IP settings of your internet device (under Network in System Preferences) solves the issue much quicker and easier, for me anyway.

Just another error that makes working in Apples eco-system all the more fun and exciting...

Answer (score 0):

There was no one particular procedure that seemed to do it in my case: restarted router, restarted Mac, restarted Xcode, recreated profiles on developer website, viewed them in Xcode, recreated archives, attempted just validating for App Store. All of these things over and over again.

My experience has been that you should just kept trying until suddenly it works. Which is sadly not the magic button to click that I was looking for.

Possibly the fact that I managed only twice in the last dozen or so upload attempts in the morning from here in the UK (making it approx 02:30 over there in the US), indicates it's perhaps an iTunes overloaded problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, though none of the suggested steps solved my problem, other than using the Application Loader.

However, one thing that bothered me was a warning message saying that:

> The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message.

It came to me that it might be the reason why Xcode's uploading might be messed up, since it locks at the `Sending API usage to iTunes Connect`.

Some people mention it in [some posts here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257597/the-resulting-api-analysis-is-too-large-when-upload-app-to-mac-store).

Answer (score 0):

For me Network is not allowing to upload the build as office wireless is having firewall so I had to move to other wi-fi to upload the build.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another possible answer here that fixed it for me.

I was on a VPN at work. Disabling this and trying again worked.